# Массив из массивов

Tags: c, массивы

Как я могу создать массив из массивов в C, и чтобы каждый массив было по длине 2, а сам массив из массивов по длине 99?

Comment: Вопрос в том, массивы каких элементов? В C надо четко указывать - это массив int, это - массив double...

Answer (score 2):

Это называется двумерным массивом

```
type massiv[99][2];
```

`type` подставьте сами, вы его не указали в вопросе...

Это массив из 99 массивов `type[2]`.